# Why does RewriteRule only work when I change the line position?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following lines in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/$ ?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(20\d\d)/page/([0-9]+)/$ ?yearMeasure=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(20\d\d)/$ ?yearMeasure=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/page/([0-9]+)/$ ?category=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ ?category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(20\d\d)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ ?type=post&year=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA]
```

When the file is left as above, the server does not capture /page/1/. Rather, it returns a 404 error. However, when I flip the second and third lines, everything works perfectly. Why is this?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^(20\d\d)/page/([0-9]+)/$ ?yearMeasure=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/$ ?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(20\d\d)/$ ?yearMeasure=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/page/([0-9]+)/$ ?category=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ ?category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(20\d\d)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ ?type=post&year=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA]
```

**Edit:**

After a few minutes of experimenting, it seems that the line that comes directly after `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+)` is ineffectual.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any [`RewriteCond`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) belongs to the `RewriteRule` directly following it

> The RewriteCond directive defines a rule condition. One or more RewriteCond can precede a RewriteRule directive. The following rule is then only used if both the current state of the URI matches its pattern, and if these conditions are met.

```
1. RewriteCond ...
2. RewriteRule ...
3. RewriteCond ...
4. RewriteRule ...
5. RewriteRule ...
```

So in this case condition 1 belongs to rule 2, and condition 3 belongs to rule 4, and finally rule 5 has no condition at all.

---

This means, when you have

```
1. RewriteCond ...
2. RewriteRule ...
3. RewriteRule ...
```

and switch rules 2 and 3,

```
1. RewriteCond ...
3. RewriteRule ...
2. RewriteRule ...
```

the condition belongs to the other rule.

---

When you use the first set of rules and request `/page/1/?id=5`, it would work, because now the preceding condition "`QUERY_STRING` matches `id=([0-9]+)`" is met.